# What is the most modern way to handle Haskell testing?

Tags: testing, haskell

I only recently started working on my latest Haskell project, and would really like to test it. I was wondering where testing currently stands, with regards to the cutting edge frameworks, test running procedures and test code organization. It seems that previously tests were just a separate binary that returned a different exit code if tests passed or failed - is this still the currently adopted setup, or are there other ways to integrate with cabal now?

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/#test-suites

Comment: what kind of cutting edge do you need? imo banishing stuff like `fromJust`, etc. from your code is a better way to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

[Quickcheck](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction_to_QuickCheck) may not be cutting edge anymore (at least for Haskell practitioners).
But in combination with [HUnit](http://hunit.sourceforge.net/) it's quite easy to get almost 100% coverage (I use [HPC](http://projects.unsafeperformio.com/hpc/) for converage analysis).